# Jenkins on Linux - Logs

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins installation in a Linux VM. I'm looking for the file *jenkins.wrapper.log* to find out when the app was started/stopped. Unfortunately I can't find the file?

How else can I retrieve when Jenkins started/stopped?

Comment: Why do you think such file should exist? What do you expect there? Should this be created by the application that you're testing?

Comment: When installed on Windows Jenkins logs its starts and stops in the file _jenkins.wrapper.log_. On the other hand, if Jenkins runs on Linux it seems not to create the above file. Where else is it protocolled?

Comment: I would say it depends on how you install it. Using the `.war`, Debian Package, yum package, ..? In general, `/var/log/jenkins/` might be worth looking at, at least for the non-war installs.

Comment: We used _.war_ file for Jenkins installation. There are log files in _/var/log/jenkins/_ folder but I can't find information about when Jenkins was started/stopped.